# reference the roles/users created via Web Site Admin tool, in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

In my ASP.NET Web Application with C#, I used the Web Site Administration tool to create users and passwords.
I do some actions in the aspx file based on roles, e.g.:

```
<RoleGroups>
<asp:RoleGroup Roles="Administrators">
```

My question is: how can I reference the roles/users created as mentioned, within the code-behind (C#) file:

> E.g. If role=Administrators, do this...
>
> If user = admin/john/whatever, do this...

Thank you!
Anna

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
    if (Roles.IsUserInRole("Administrators"))
    {  
       // do something for administrator
    }
```

For Users, you can get a User like this to get the currently logged in user

```
    Dim userInfo As MembershipUser = Membership.GetUser( HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name)
```

and there is a whole bigger Membership API you can use to do what you like. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648345.aspx

Comment: Thank you Furqan, and what about users?